# Newbie Python Exercise - find distance between points.

Tags: python

OK so, in my first programming class.  I did all the homework exercises except this one.  I cannot quite wrap my head around what is asking me to do (related to the text I read) so I thought I would ask here.

> Q:  A dartboard of radius 10 and the wall it is hanging on are
>   represented using the two-dimensional coordinate system, with the
>   board's center at coordinate (0, 0).  Variables x and y store the x-
>   and y-coordinate of a dart hit.  Write an expression using variables x
>   and y that evaluates to true if the dart hits (is within) the
>   dartboard, and evaluate the expression for these dart coordinates:
>
> (0,0) (10,10) (6,-6) (-7,8)

I honestly do not know where to start here.  Help? Hints?

Comment: You need to find the distance of the dart from the center of the dartboard.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem isn't Python: it's reading English.

You have a dartboard at `(0,0)` of radius 10.  You're asked to write a program to look at the four points you're given and tell whether or not they would hit the dartboard.

What's the formula for distance from a center (x0, y0)?

```
r = sqrt((x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2)
```

If you calculate `r <= 10`, it hits the dartboard.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer we need for homework problems – helping the OP understand the problem rather than doing the work.